# Custom dropdown list not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create a custom drop down list.I want to have to two options in my drop down list i.e predefined and custom. When I select custom from the list it is not getting selected. I have this code so far which is not working.

```
    <html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function DropDown(el) {
    this.dd = el;
    this.initEvents();
}
DropDown.prototype = {
    initEvents : function() {
        var obj = this;

        obj.dd.on('click', function(event){
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
            event.stopPropagation();
        }); 
    }
}
$(function() {

                var dd = new DropDown( $('#dd') );

                $(document).click(function() {
                    // all dropdowns
                    $('.wrapper-dropdown-5').removeClass('active');
                });

            });

</script>
<style>
.wrapper-dropdown-5 {
    /* Size & position */
    position: relative;
    width: 144px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 12px 15px;

    /* Styles */
    background: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
.wrapper-dropdown-5:after { /* Little arrow */
    content: "";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 165px;
    margin-top: -3px;
    border-width: 6px 6px 0 6px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #067ab4 transparent;
}
.wrapper-dropdown-5 .dropdown {
    /* Size & position */
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: -40;
    right: 0;

    /* Styles */

    list-style: none;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;

    /* Hiding */
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.wrapper-dropdown-5 .dropdown li {
    padding: 0 10px ;
}
.wrapper-dropdown-5 .dropdown li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #067ab4;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;

}
.wrapper-dropdown-5 .dropdown li:last-of-type a {
    border: none;
}
.wrapper-dropdown-5 .dropdown li i {
    margin-right: 5px;
    color: inherit;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
/* Hover state */
.wrapper-dropdown-5 .dropdown li:hover a {
    color: #57a9d9;
}
/* Active state */
.wrapper-dropdown-5.active {
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-bottom: none;
    color: white;
}
.wrapper-dropdown-5.active:after {
    border-color: #067ab4 transparent;
}
 .wrapper-dropdown-5.active .dropdown {
    border-bottom: 0px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    max-height: 400px;
}
div#dd
{
color: #067ab4;
font: 30px tahoma;
display: inline-block;
}
div#textA
{
display: inline-block;
font: 30px tahoma;
padding-left: 20px;
}
div#textB
{
display: inline-block;
font: 30px tahoma;
padding-left: 6px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>   <div id="textA">I want to select a</div>
         <div id="dd" class="wrapper-dropdown-5" tabindex="1">Predefined
    <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-user"></i>Custom</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div  id="textB">profile</div>
    </body>
   <html>
```

Comment: Why would it work...there's no event attached to clicking Custom - or anything in any dropdown?

Comment: I am new to javascript/jquery. Can you please fix my code so that it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're going for? I just used jquery to swap the text on a click event, needs some tweaking I think to your css though to get it to swap back.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/R5aHa/

```
$('#dd2').click(function(){
var selected = $('#dd2').text();

if($('#dd2').text(selected)){
    $('#dd2').html("Predefined");
    $('#dd').html("Custom");  
} else {
    $('#dd').html("Predefined");
    $('#dd2').html("Custom");
}
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You must attach an event listener to the nav item for it to work, otherwise you have all this javascript written and nothing calling it to work.

[Event Listeners](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

Comment: +1, But at stack overflow we encourage users to include a summary of linked content in answers. That way, if the link becomes invalid, the answer is still valid.